# Are there any js libraries for reading OpenStreetMap History data?

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, openstreetmap, time, history

I want to do time based mapping on openstreetmap data in the Kathmandu, Nepal area. I think i have two options

1. Using OpenStreetMap Change files (OSC)
2. Using OpenStreetmap History files (OSH)

I have found js libraries for reading OSC files. Are there any js libraries for reading OSH data?

Comment: For any specific area? There are many examples of timelapse changes online.

Comment: For Kathmandu, Nepal. Can you give some examples?